# visual studio 2010 and default browsers

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

Is there any way that I can get visual studio (2010 or other) to decide what browser to launch depending on the type of project I am working on?  I prefer to use IE when I am developing Silverlight projects, and Chrome / Firefox / anything but IE when I am working on ASP.NET projects.  Of course manually setting my default browser is always an option depending on what I am doing, but I feel like VS2010 should be smart enough to handle this for me.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [WoVS Default Browser Switcher](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/bb424812-f742-41ef-974a-cdac607df921/). Whilst it won't automatically detect the project type, it allows you to set the default browser in one click.

Comment: that is close enough for me.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

use this [extension](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/bb424812-f742-41ef-974a-cdac607df921/)

It's pretty good.